# CSS Slider moves to left

Tags: html, css, slider

I have created an slider with css but when I get to the last element it moves to the left side.

```css
/*Slider */

input[name="slider-select-element"] {
  display: none;
}
#slider-arrows {
  margin: -10% auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
#slider-box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
}
#slider-container {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
}
.element-1,
.element-2,
.element-3 {
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
}
.element-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.element-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
.element-3 {
  background-color: green;
}
.slider-element {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%
}
#element1:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(2),
#element2:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(3),
#element3:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
#element1:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(3),
#element2:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(1),
#element3:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#element1:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(2):before,
#element2:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(3):before,
#element3:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(1):before {
  color: black;
  content: "\f054";
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
#element1:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(3):before,
#element2:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(1):before,
#element3:checked ~ #slider-arrows label:nth-child(2):before {
  color: black;
  content: "\f053";
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
#element1:checked ~ #slider-container #slider-box {
  margin-left: 0;
}
#element2:checked ~ #slider-container #slider-box {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
#element3:checked ~ #slider-container #slider-box {
  margin-left: -200%;
}
#slider-arrows label {
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
#slider-box {
  /*chrome y safari */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease;
  /*mozilla */
  -moz-transition: all 0.75s ease;
  /* I explorer */
  -ms-transition: all 0.75s ease;
  /*Opera*/
  -o-transition: all 0.75s ease;
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
}
```

```html
<!-- Slider -->
<section>

  <!-- Controles -->
  <input type="radio" name="slider-select-element" id="element1" checked="checked" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider-select-element" id="element2" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider-select-element" id="element3" />
  <!-- Terminan Controles -->

  <div id="slider-container">
    <div id="slider-box">
      <div class="slider-element">
        <article class="element-1">

        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-element">
        <article class="element-2">

        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-element">
        <article class="element-3">

        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slider-arrows">
    <label for="element1"></label>
    <label for="element2"></label>
    <label for="element3"></label>
  </div>

</section>
```

I've found two solutions but i don't know if they are the correct solution.

1.-Add to `.slider-container` a `margin-left: 10%`.

2.-Add `position:relavite` to `<section>` and `position:absolute` `margin-left:10%` to `slider-arrow`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around with it for a bit, I'd go with your first suggestion. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95kpw6vc/4/).

I basically just changed this line:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

To this:

```
margin: 0 auto auto 10%;
```

This just ensures that there is a 10% width between the slider container and the left side of the page. If your slider container width is going to be 80%, it makes sense that each side has 10% width, assuming it is centered. Therefore everything will line up nicely. No adjusting to position is needed.